# Relative path in virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

I'm migrating an e-commerce app from an old php framework to ASP.NET MVC. Some products have links to other products in their descriptions. I wrote a small app to import everything from the old site to the new site and now I want to update those links too. I would like to make the links relative, but relative links won't work on `localhost` because the site is in a virtual directory.

Old link: `http://domain/index.php?productID=1234`
New link: `/product/1234`

The new link won't work in `localhost` because it will be translated to `localhost/product/1234` instead of `localhost/virtualdirectory/product/1234`.

I've been googling for a solution for quite some time but I can't seem to find anything. Do you have any ideas about how to solve this problem?

I actually came up with a solution while writing the question, but I'm going to post this anyway, maybe you come up with a better solution.

Comment: I probably don't fully understand, but how does a virtual directory (I guess that's an IIS virtual directory you talk about) affect testing on localhost? EDIT: Are you using the IIS Web Express server?

Comment: Have you tried using the tilde (~) approach.  More details here: http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2004/05/05/avoiding-problems-with-relative-and-absolute-urls-in-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered not running your app in a virtual directory? While it may be the default in Visual Studio, it can be changed.

Comment: I have not considered this because I don't know how to set up multiple apps to **not** run in a virtual directory. Can you point me to a tutorial or something?

Comment: What is your current setup - how is your localhost site hosted?

Comment: I use a local IIS Web server.

Comment: The easiest way is to assign each site a different port, thus avoiding this virtual directory difference with the deployed site

Comment: Ok, I thought about that too.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was using links like this: `../../product/1234`

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, right-click on your project and click "Properties."  Under the "Web" tab, enter the virtual path in the box that says "Virtual Path:"

For example, /MyVirtualPath

In your code, make sure that your links are written like "../MyVirtualPath/".